# match English word with optional dot,slash,numbers existence

Tags: .net, regex

I want to match the following words

tree ,
tree.com ,
tree123 ,
123tree ,
tree-up ,

I made the following condition..it works properly but I want to join them in one regular expression

```
bool res1=Regex.IsMatch(term, "^[a-zA-Z-.]+$",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)  
//works well but it matches . and - if they come alone  i want a solution ?!

bool res2=Regex.IsMatch(term, "^[a-zA-Z-.]+[0-9]+$",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) //works well 

bool res3=Regex.IsMatch(term,"^[0-9]+[a-zA-Z-.]+$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)//works well
```

I know I can use

```
if(res1 || res2 || res3 ) {}
```

but i want to join those expressions in 1 expression

Comment: It doesn't work properly or it does work properly?

Comment: sorry I've edited my question , it works properly separately , and i want to join them in one regular expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lookahead zero-width assertion to check to make sure that at least one letter (or anything else that is required) is included

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z-.]+$
```

Comment: thnx aloot ,I'm new to regex but I really loved it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do not want leading, trailing or consecutive dots or hyphens, I suggest this pattern:

```
bool res = Regex.IsMatch(term, "^[a-z0-9]+(?>[-.][a-z0-9]+)*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

If you want to be sure there's at least one letter, you can change the pattern to:

```
^(?>[0-9]+(?>[-.][0-9]+)*[-.]?)?[a-z]+(?>[-.]?[a-z0-9]+)*$
```

[demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F%3E%5B0-9%5D%2B%28%3F%3E%5B-.%5D%5B0-9%5D%2B%29*%5B-.%5D%3F%29%3F%5Ba-z%5D%2B%28%3F%3E%5B-.%5D%3F%5Ba-z0-9%5D%2B%29*%5Cr%3F%24&i=tree%0D%0Atree.com%0D%0Atree123%0D%0A123tree%0D%0Atree-up%0D%0A123%0D%0AA%0D%0Aa..b%0D%0Aa.1.b&o=im)